# Diagonalize a quasi-uniform tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, tridiagonal-matrices

How to diagonalize the following matrix?

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0  & a& 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
a& 0  & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & b & 0  & b & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & b & 0  & b \\
\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & b & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is a symmetric matrix. So you can apply simultaneous row and column operations. Then you will get $A=CDC^T$. Firstly try $(-b/a)R_1+R_3$ and $(-b/a)C_1+C_3$. Then add 2nd row to first row and 2nd column to first column and go on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to get the analytic solution？

Comment: At the end of the processes, the diagonal matrix becomes $(2a,-a/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,...)$(these are diagonal entries) I really don't understand what do you mean by analytic solution.

Comment: Do you mean the eigenvalues are (2a,-a/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,...)? I am quite sure those are not the eigenvalues. For example, if the dimension is 4, then the eigenvalues are $$ -\frac{\sqrt{-\sqrt{a^4+4 b^4}+a^2+2 b^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{-\sqrt{a^4+4 b^4}+a^2+2 b^2}}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^4+4 b^4}+a^2+2 b^2}}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^4+4 b^4}+a^2+2 b^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write in answer box. Apply the row operations $[(-b/a)R_1+R_3 \to R_3]$, $[-R_3+R_5 \to R_5]$, ..., $[-R_{2k+1}+R_{2k+3} \to R_{2k+3}]$ Denote this operations by the matrices $C_i$ and their corresponding columns operations are denoted by $C_i^T$. Then (let the matrix in question is $A$)

$C_sC_{s-1}...C_1AC_1^T...C_s^T$ is the following matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
A &  & & & & & \\
 & 0 &  &  &  &  &\\
 &  & B & & & & \\
 &  & & 0 & & & \\
 &  & & & B &  & \\
 &  & & & & 0 & \\
 &  & & & & & B \\
&  & & & & &  & . \\
&  & & & & & & & .
\end{bmatrix}

where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a \\
a & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b \\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $0$ is $2 \times 2$ zero matrix. Then apply the following row operations

$R_{4k+2}+R_{4k+1}=R_{4k+1}$ and their corresponding column operations $C_{4k+2}+C_{4k+1}=C_{4k+1}$simultaneously. Let these row operations denoted by $E_k$. Then

$E_t...E_1(C_sC_{s-1}...C_1AC_1^T...C_s^T)E_1^T...E_t^T$ is the following matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
A &  & & & & & \\
 & 0 &  &  &  &  &\\
 &  & B & & & & \\
 &  & & 0 & & & \\
 &  & & & B &  & \\
 &  & & & & 0 & \\
 &  & & & & & B \\
&  & & & & &  & . \\
&  & & & & & & & .
\end{bmatrix}

where

where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
2a & a \\
a & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
2b & b \\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $0$ is $2 \times 2$ zero matrix. Then apply the following row operations

$(-1/2)R_{4k+1}+R_{4k+2}=R_{4k+2}$ and their corresponding column operations simultaneously. Let these row operations denoted by $F_k$. Then

$F_t^T...F_1^T(E_t...E_1C_sC_{s-1}...C_1AC_1^T...C_s^TE_1^T...E_t^T)F_1^T...F_t^T$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $2a,-a/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,2b,-b/2,0,0,...$